# Adding Youtube iframe API at runtime - React Component

Tags: javascript, react.js, youtube

So we created a component where we have a couple of Yotube iframes and we import the Youtube iframe API like this way. It's working and we achieve what we expected. I would appreciate any comments about this code!

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.init();

   window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = e => {
     this.YT = window.YT;

     this.individualsPlayer = new window.YT.Player(this.YTIndividualsRef, {
       events: {
         onStateChange: this.onPlayerStateChange
       }
     });

     this.managersPlayer = new window.YT.Player(this.YTManagersRef, {
       events: {
         onStateChange: this.onPlayerStateChange
       }
     });
   }; 
}

init() {
    const tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}

onPlayerStateChange = e => {
  switch (e.data) {
    case window.YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
      console.log('playing');
    break;
  }
}
```